# SQL - Parse JsonData and making a table data

Tags: sql, json

I have sample declare json string which i want to make it a table data, the problem is, my OPENJSON column is NULL.

```
 declare @JsonString varchar(MAX)
    set  @JsonString=
    '{"status":{"code":"0","name":"RCRD_LOADED","status":"Success","message":"Record sucessfully loaded"},"records":[{"recordtype":"inventoryitem","id":"24","itemid":"Coupon Bond (A4)","displayname":"","locationquantityonhand":"","locationquantityavailable":"","locationquantitycommitted":"","locationquantitybackordered":""},{"recordtype":"inventoryitem","id":"23","itemid":"P.E. Uniform","displayname":"P.E. Uniform","locationquantityonhand":"","locationquantityavailable":"","locationquantitycommitted":"","locationquantitybackordered":""},{"recordtype":"inventoryitem","id":"16","itemid":"Test Item","displayname":"Test Item","locationquantityonhand":"","locationquantityavailable":"","locationquantitycommitted":"","locationquantitybackordered":""},{"recordtype":"inventoryitem","id":"15","itemid":"Text book","displayname":"AMA textbook","locationquantityonhand":"","locationquantityavailable":"","locationquantitycommitted":"","locationquantitybackordered":""},{"recordtype":"inventoryitem","id":"14","itemid":"Uniform-02","displayname":"AMA Uniform","locationquantityonhand":"","locationquantityavailable":"","locationquantitycommitted":"","locationquantitybackordered":""}]}'
        
    
    SELECT * FROM  
     OPENJSON ( @JsonString )  
    WITH (   
                  RecordType   varchar(200) '$.records.recordtype' ,  
                  ItemID     datetime     '$.records.id',  
                  ItemDetails varchar(200) '$.records.itemid',  
                  Quantity int          '$.records.locationquantityonhand'  
     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as said below.

Pass "records" to `OPENJSON`, observe the code below.

And then map the variables as shown below.

```
SELECT * FROM  
OPENJSON ( @JsonString,'$."records"')  
WITH (   
              RecordType   varchar(200) '$.recordtype' ,  
              ItemID     varchar     '$.id',  
              ItemDetails varchar(200) '$.itemid',  
              Quantity int          '$.locationquantityonhand'  
 )
```